# Why is electroosmotic flow plug-like?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid, microfluidics

[image]

Hey, I am studying for a microfluidic exam and can't wrap my head around electro osmotic flow: why is the velocity profile plug-like? The fluid motion in the bulk phase away from the double layer is driven by the viscous interaction with the double layer. But in each interaction some energy is dissipated, so I imagine the velocity to drop towards the centre of the channel. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is depth of the channel (the dimension in the viewing direction of the picture) substantially smaller?

Comment: otherwise it seems to be saying it behaves as if the walls were moving... which would also explain it - because (??) the boundary condition near the walls would be no longer 0-velocity, but similar velocity to the resulting flow (??)